# viewDidAppear for tabbar based apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'd like to do something when a particular tab appears.  Meaning, the user has clicked the tab view's tab button.  viewDidAppear doesn't fire when this happens.  How else can I hook into the tab click event?

Answer (score 11):

You can implement this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
  [viewController viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

in your Tab Bar Delegate, so your viewDidAppear method will be called properly.

Comment: This works *except* for the very first tab, I believe. That is, I think the `didSelect` method only gets called on a user selection not when the tab bar controller opens at launch.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`-tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1) in your tab bar delegate.