# Motion function not working after changing tab in Tabbed Application

Tags: ios, motion-detection

i'm pretty new.

I'm working on a Tabbed Application.

I wanted to have one of the tab with Shake feature, incorporated

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.subtype   == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        NSLog(@"shook");
    }
}
```

this works perfectly fine until I tab away from this FirstViewController to other and then come back.  Once I return to FirstViewController, the shake function doesn't seem to work at all.   any idea?

i do have the other components as below

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self canBecomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the viewDidAppear is not be called every time you switch between tabs: [viewDidAppear for tabbar based apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758798/viewdidappear-for-tabbar-based-apps)

As suggested by the answer there, implement the UITabBarController delegate *didSelectViewController* and call the viewDidAppear method of the view controller.

Or still implement the delegate and just detect the view controller selected and if it is FirstViewController, call the method *canBecomeFirstResponder*.

For example, if you have declared the FirstViewController as a property of the tab bar:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
  if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]) {
      [viewController canBecomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```